# How can I assign an id and class with $this->Html->link(..);?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    'more',
    array(
        'controller'=>'posts',
        'action'=>'view',
        $post['Post']['id']
    ) 
);
```

How can I assign an id and class for this anchor/link? I want to override its css rule.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HTML attributes can be specified in an array as the third parameter.

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    'more',
    array(
        'controller'=>'posts',
        'action'=>'view',
        $post['Post']['id']
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 'myId',
        'class' => 'myClass'
    )
);
```

More info in the [Cookbook 2.x](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::link) for the 2.x version or [Cookbook 1.3](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/HTML.html#link) for CakePHP 1.3.