# CakePHP 2.4 : How to get id value from postlink in cakephp ?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am trying to get id value from postlink. here is the delete postlink in index.ctp

```
 <?php 

        echo $this->Form->postLink(

            $this->Html->tag('i', '', array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove')),
            array('action' => 'delete', $user['User']['id'],'class'=>'del'),
            array('escape'=>false,'class'=>'btn btn-sm btn-danger'),
        __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $user['User']['id'])
    );

    ?>
```

I have tried bellow code by jquery

```
$('document').ready(function(){
      var x=jQuery(this).attr("id");
      alert(x);
});
```

Here I am not getting any value.How to get this id for ajax submission ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the value id value and it doesn't exist against the link.

If you want to get the value of id you need to define it first. Check out the following links for some examples on how assign extra values using the cakePHP html helper.

- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::link
- [How can I assign an id and class with $this->Html->link(..);?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889955/how-can-i-assign-an-id-and-class-with-this-html-link)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data-attribute`.

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(

        $this->Html->tag('i', '', array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove')),
        array('action' => 'delete', $user['User']['id'],'class'=>'del'),
        array('escape'=>false,'class'=>'btn btn-sm btn-danger', 'data-idVal' => $user['User']['id']),
    __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $user['User']['id'])
);
```

And then

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  var x=jQuery(this).data("idVal");
  alert(x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually $this->Form->postLink() doesn't assign a id to the delete link. You can do this as follows

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(

    $this->Html->tag('i', '', array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove')),
    array('action' => 'delete', $user['User']['id'],'class'=>'del'),
    array('escape'=>false,'class'=>'btn btn-sm btn-danger', 'id' => $user['User']['id']),
    __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $user['User']['id'])
);
```

And to get the id you have to write your code in the .click event of jquery similar to following

```
$( ".del" ).click(function() {
    var x=jQuery(this).attr("id");
    alert(x); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good practice but I have solved this problem an easy way

I have change this postlink to

```
<button class="del" id=<?php echo $user['User']['id']; ?>>Delete </delete>
```

Now I have gotten this id by

```
$('.del').click(function(){
var x=$(this).attr("id");
alert(X);
}
```